# How can I add a row to an HTML table that has a text input field inside?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently, I am creating a table that takes in first and last names. After filling out a row,I want a new row to appear (right now, I am just making a button so that I can get this functionality correct).

In this row, I want to create 2 cells that have text inputs inside which can be used for other names.

**Question**: How can I insert a text input into my HTML table rows and cells?

```js
const table = document.querySelector('#table');

function lineMessage(msg) {
    document.querySelector('#myMessage').textContent += msg;
}

function groupMessage(msg) {
    document.querySelector('#myMessage').innerHTML += msg + '<br/>';
}

function addRow() {
    var row = table.insertRow(2);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML = "cell1";
    cell2.innerHTML = "cell2";
}
```

```css
th {
    width: 50vmin;
    height: 10vmin;
    font-size: 20pt;
}

td {
    width: 50vmin;
    height: 5vmin;
}

input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
}

#submit {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    border: 0;
    position: relative;
    left: 82vmin;
}

#myConsole {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    height: 25vmin;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
        <meta name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="author" content="Christian Davis">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <title>Random Group Generator</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table id="table" border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>First Name:</th>
                <th>Last Name:</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th><input type="text"></th>
                <th><input type="text"></th>
            </tr>
        </table> <br>

        <button onclick="addRow()">Add Row</button>
        <button id="submit">Submit</button>
        <p id="myConsole">&gt;&nbsp;<span id="myMessage"></span></p>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you meant that you want to add another row with inputs at the bottom of the table you can edit your  `addRow` function into something like this:

```js
function addRow() {
    const row = table.insertRow(-1);
    
    const cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    const cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

    const input1 = document.createElement("input");
    input1.type = "text";
    cell1.appendChild(input1);

    var input2 = document.createElement("input");
    input2.type = "text";
    cell2.appendChild(input2);
}
```

Please notice that In order to insert a row at the bottom of the table I used `insertRow(-1)`

---

And this is the final result:

```js
const table = document.querySelector('#table');

function lineMessage(msg) {
    document.querySelector('#myMessage').textContent += msg;
}

function groupMessage(msg) {
    document.querySelector('#myMessage').innerHTML += msg + '<br/>';
}

function addRow() {
    const row = table.insertRow(-1);
    
    const cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    const cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

    const input1 = document.createElement("input");
    input1.type = "text";
    cell1.appendChild(input1);

    var input2 = document.createElement("input");
    input2.type = "text";
    cell2.appendChild(input2);
}
```

```css
th {
    width: 50vmin;
    height: 10vmin;
    font-size: 20pt;
}

td {
    width: 50vmin;
    height: 5vmin;
}

input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
}

#submit {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    border: 0;
    position: relative;
    left: 82vmin;
}

#myConsole {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    height: 25vmin;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
        <meta name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="author" content="Christian Davis">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <title>Random Group Generator</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table id="table" border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>First Name:</th>
                <th>Last Name:</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th><input type="text"></th>
                <th><input type="text"></th>
            </tr>
        </table> <br>

        <button onclick="addRow()">Add Row</button>
        <button id="submit">Submit</button>
        <p id="myConsole">&gt;&nbsp;<span id="myMessage"></span></p>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a few approaches, one is below with explanatory comments in the code:

```js
// I've removed the various functions that aren't used relevant to the problem,
// and aren't used in the code posted here; if you're trying to solve a problem
// it's best to try to remove irrelevant code while you're working on it (that
// way you've got less code to sift through, and usually less scrolling through
// the document(s):
const table = document.querySelector('#table');

// my personal preference is to declare functions as const variables, rather
// than using the function declaration, and relying on hoisting so I'm commenting
// this out, and doing that instead:
/*
function addRow() {
  var row = table.insertRow(2);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  cell1.innerHTML = "cell1";
  cell2.innerHTML = "cell2";
  document.createElement("input");
}
*/

// using an Arrow function expression to define the function, and passing in a
// reference to the Event Object that triggered the function call:
const addRow = (evt) => {
  // here we need to create a table row with two table cells and in those cells
  // create a single <input>, so:
  let tr = document.createElement('tr'),
    td = document.createElement('td'),
    input = document.createElement('input');
    
  // the default type of an <input> element is "text", but I prefer to be
  // explicit, and set that in the code:
  input.type = "text";
  
  // here we append the created <input> to the <td>:
  td.append(input);
  
  // here we append the <td>, along with a clone of that <td> to the <tr>:
  tr.append(td, td.cloneNode(true));
  
  // if the author doesn't define a <tbody> element to wrap the contents,
  // all browsers (so far as I've worked with so far) automatically do so;
  // so here we retrieve the <tbody> descendant of an element with the id
  // of "table", and append the <tr> to that element:
  document.querySelector('#table tbody').append(tr);
}

document.querySelector('.addRow').addEventListener('click', addRow);
```

```css
th {
  width: 50vmin;
  height: 10vmin;
  font-size: 20pt;
}

td {
  width: 50vmin;
  height: 5vmin;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 18pt;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
}

#submit {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  border: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 82vmin;
}

#myConsole {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 25vmin;
}
```

```html
<table id="table" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>First Name:</th>
    <th>Last Name:</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <!-- a <th> is a table-heading element, whereas the <input> elements are part of
         the content, and so should appear in <td> (table-data) cells: --> 
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br>

<!-- don't use event attributes in the HTML where possible, using JavaScript to bind
     the JavaScript event-handlers is usually makes the resulting code easier to maintain,
     here I've removed the "onclick" attribute, and added a class-name (this isn't
     strictly necessary, but it's an easier method to demonstrate) by which the event-handler
     can be bound: -->
<button class="addRow">Add Row</button>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

There are other ways, though; one of which is to simply clone the existing elements, as shown below:

```js
const addRow = (evt) => {
  // caching a reference to the <tbody> element:
  let tbody = document.querySelector('#table tbody'),
      // looking within the <tbody> element to retrieve the last
      // element child node, and cloning it (including its content):
      clone = tbody.lastElementChild.cloneNode(true);
  
  // here we use Element.querySelectorAll() to find all <input> elements:
  clone.querySelectorAll('input')
    // using NodeList.prototype.forEach() in order to iterate through
    // the NodeList:
    .forEach(
      // 'el' is a reference to the current Node of the NodeList,
      // and here we set the value of the element to its default-value
      // in order that the user-entered value isn't copied, and the
      // <input> returns to the normal "base-state" in which it
      // appeared on page-load:
      (el) => el.value = el.defaultValue
    )
    
  // appending the cloned <tr> (and its content) to the <tbody>:
  tbody.append(clone);
}

// selecting the first/only element matching the supplied CSS selector:
document.querySelector('.addRow')
  // using EventTarget.addEventListener() to bind the addRow function
  // as the event-handler for the 'click' event:
  .addEventListener('click', addRow);
```

```css
th {
  width: 50vmin;
  height: 10vmin;
  font-size: 20pt;
}

td {
  width: 50vmin;
  height: 5vmin;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 18pt;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
}

#submit {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  border: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 82vmin;
}

#myConsole {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 25vmin;
}
```

```html
<table id="table" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name:</th>
      <th>Last Name:</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button class="addRow">Add Row</button>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

References:

- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`Element.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append).
- [`Element.lastElementChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/lastElementChild).
- [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector).
- [`Element.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [`Node.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode).
- [`NodeList` `forEach()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).